# How to use DateTime::diff() with DateTime::format('%R') in PHP 5.2?

Tags: php, datetime, diff

There are many questions (and solutions) about DateTime::diff() around, but I haven't found any solution to the following piece of code:

```
$start = new DateTime('13:00');
$end = new DateTime('02:00');

$difference = $start->diff($end);

if ($difference->format('%R') === '-')
{
    $passedMidnight = true;
}
else
{
    $passedMidnight = false;
}
```

This is basically what i'm looking for in PHP 5.2: A way to find out if $end passes midnight compared to $start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be enough to just check whether  two dates are on the same day?

```
$start = new DateTime('13:00');
$end = new DateTime('02:00');

if ($start->format('Y-m-d') == $end->format('Y-m-d'))
 echo "Midnight has NOT passed";
else
 echo "Midnight has passed";
```

I can't see a scenario where this would not work because DST usually shifts the clocks at 2 in the morning (right?).

Comment: $start->format('Y-m-d') and $end->format('Y-m-d') have the exact same value, which returns Midnight has NOT passed. While $end is actually passed midnight considering $start.

Comment: @Pestario no, it hasn't. "02:00" without a date is "02:00" *this morning*. If that's not what you want, you need to explicitly say so (e.g. using an explicit date)

Comment: @Pekka Thats the issue, I only have a two times.

Comment: @Pestario that doesn't make sense. "02:00" is in the morning of the current day - it's the same convention all over the world. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Pekka In the example I posted in the question `$difference->format('%R')` returns either '-' or nothing. It returns a '-' if $end is passed midnight of $start. So magically it knows that 02:00 is later then 13:00 without giving a date. this is what i'm looking for. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @Pestario That is not what "R" does. "R" is negative because `27.05.2011 02:00` is earlier than `27.05.2011 13:00`. Output `$end->format("Y-m-d H:i")` and see for yourself.

Comment: You are right. I always thought it knew this 'magically' haha. I'll post my final solution within 8 hours here. Thanks to you and PFHayes I got the right idea to fix this. Hopefully this will be of some help to others as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're constructing the DateTime objects with just times, then what you really want to do is see if $end comes earlier in the day than $start. You can use the getTimestamp function for this.

```
if ($end->getTimestamp() < $start->getTimestamp()) {
    echo "Midnight has passed";
} else {
    echo "Midnight has not passed";
}
```

Comment: Problem here is that DateTime::getTimestamp() is PHP 5.3 or newer, thats the initial question, that I need to get this working on a PHP 5.2 environment.

Comment: In that case, you may just want to split the input string into hour and minute portions, and compare them directly.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I'll post my final solution as a seperate answer within 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with doing this, thanks to Pekka and PFHayes for the ideas:

```
$start = strtotime('13:00');
$end = strtotime('01:00');

if ($end < $start)
{
    echo "Midnight has passed";
}
else
{
    echo "Midnight has not passed";
}
```